# Calculate balances (in database) of different currencies (rates in API) - using javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, api

I would appreciate some help.

I have a database and API. The database has the balance for each crypto_currency and the API has the current rate for the cryptocurrency in euros.

**#The data sources**

API Data

```
data:
0: {id: "bitcoin", symbol: "btc", current_price: 47000,…}
1: {id: "ethereum", symbol: "eth", current_price: 1500,…}
2: {id: "monero", symbol: "xmr", current_price: 200,…}
```

Database

- id
- balance
- api_id
- currency_symbol

**#Notes:**

- api_id in the database is the same as id in the API
- current_rate

**#What I want to achieve:**
I want to make the following calculation:

1. Calculate the balance for all currencies
   balance(from database)*current_rate
2. sum (balance*current_rate)

Where do I start? How do I filter the API data? One way would be to query the date from the API with query parameters, but then I would go over the API call limit if there are more users on the site, as there are on average 10 balances, so that would count as 10 API calls.

If you could guide me on where to start, how would you do it, in theory, would be appreciated.

**#One solution that worked**

I have tried this: I sort the balances desc by api_id in the database and sort the API query based on id aswell....that way the order of the currencies is the same in the API with the database, that way i can match the two things and make the calculation.

However i am thinking there is probably another way, that is more advanced.

Comment: Which programming language to you use to retrieve that API data (php? javascript? C#? something else?)?  Please [edit] your question.

Comment: using javascript